# GitHub synchronize failure result in rebase - how to get back the committed file

Tags: github, rebase

I've made a commit to GitHub but the synchronization was not successful and it abort half way. When I try to get back the files I realized the files in local has been rebased to the previous version that I submitted during the last synchronization.

The new files and editions were lost. May I know whether there's any way to get back the lost data?(now it says "Rebase origin/master ****" on my project)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

1. git log
2. copy any previous commit id.
3. git reset "commitid".

Now you will have your changes.

Then commit and rebase.

Comment: It says "Unstaged changes after reset:
M    homeword/4/.classpath". Does it mean it still keeps my last submission with all the files?(which fails last time...)

Comment: What files else it shows? If it shows all the files you have changed means, then you have got things back.

Comment: It only contains that one message but I get a newer version of my code using the commend you suggest. Thanks a lot!